# Can a bash shell script open a text file with less and then execute less commands from the script?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a shell script that would call less to open a text file.

```
less filename.txt
```

I then would like the script to search forward through the file using /'search string' or search back using ?'search string'. I also want the script to read the results into variables.

I can get a script to call less to open the file , but how do I get bash to call a series of less commands once the file is opened?  Can this be done?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use less, rather than a more script-friendly tool? grep, perhaps?

Comment: I am using grep to search a large text file for specific words and send the results to a file: ( grep -ni string filename > tempfile).

Comment: You could probably do something with an `expect` script, but can you explain *why* you want to search forward and backward? That is, *what* goal do you wish to accomplish after you have collected the information?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I have a large single text file that is a collection of books. Each book has separate chapters and each chapter has verses. Each verse has its own line. So I can use grep to search the file for a specific word with grep -ni string filename > tempfile.  This gives me the line numbers for each occurence, but I then need to open the large file and search up to find the Chapter and Book title. My goal is to type in a word and have the script provide the each occurence along with the Book, Chapter and Verse.

Comment: The traditional 1970 solution would be to write an `ed` script; somewhat more recently, they introduced `sed` for this particular use case.  There is also `vi`.  But I agree that the Awk answer is probably the best fit for your problem as described -- writing a `sed` script to perform the same task would be complicated and frustrating unless you are already very good with the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with `less` from within a script. There is no language that would control less once you turn control over to it. In order to do what you want, the easiest way is to use `grep`. For example, you can read the matching text into an array in bash with:

```
declare -a results
IFS=$'\n'                                # set IFS to only break on newline
results=( $(grep $srchterm $filename) )  # read results into array
<parse as necessary>
```

A second option would be to use `while read -r line; do... done <<< $(grep $srchterm $filename)` to essentially do the same thing.

In either case, this allows you to get the wanted lines of text into variables into your script. You can then further parse the lines into additional variables using pattern matching and substring extraction. If you do not use `grep`, then your alternative is to read the file line-by-line and manually search for the text of interest. `grep` simply automates the search part of the process for you.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know if there was a way to control less from inside a script.  It looks like grep and looping is the way to go.

Comment: In `bash` 4, you can use `readarray -t results < <(grep "$srchterm" "$filename")` to avoid the need to mess with `IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you may be able to do this more easily with `awk` if you showed us how your file is structured. You would start at the top, and each time you encountered a new book, you would note the book name. Each time you encountered a chapter, you would note the chapter name. Then each time you encountered a word you wanted, you would print the last book, chapter etc that you had seen.

Imagining your file looks something like this:

```
Book:Book 1
Chapter:Chapter 1
Word word word word
Word word word
Chapter:Chapter 2
Word word interesting word
```

Then, to find 'interesting'

```
awk -v x="interesting" -F':' '
    /^Book/    {book=$2}
    /^Chapter/ {chapter=$2}
    $0 ~ x     {print book,chapter,$0} ' OFS=":" YourFile
```

Untested - as I am on my iPad - but probably pretty close :-)

That says... set the variable `x` to the word `interesting`. When reading lines, use colons to separate fields, so everything up to the first colon is field 1 (`$1`), everything between the first and second colon is field 2 (`$2`). If you see a line starting with `Book`, remember the second field in the variable `book`. If you see a line starting with `Chapter`, remember the second field in the variable `chapter`. On any other lines, where the whole line (`$0`) contains the word `interesting`, print out the variable `book`, `chapter` and the entire current line. Oh, and by the way, separate anything I print out with colons. And do this on a file called `YourFile`.

You could keep track of the verse number yourself by incrementing it every time you encounter a new line and resetting it to zero every time you encounter a new chapter...

```
awk -v x="interesting" -F':' '
               {verse++}
    /^Book/    {book=$2}
    /^Chapter/ {chapter=$2;verse=0}
    $0 ~ x     {print book,chapter,verse,$0} ' OFS=":" YourFile
```

**Output:**

```
Book 1:Chapter 2:1:Word word interesting word
```

Comment: I am amazed this answer wasn't useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
less -pbazorka filename.txt
```

> -ppattern or --pattern=pattern
>   The -p option on the command line is equivalent to specifying +/pattern; that is, it tells less to start at the first occurrence of pattern in the file.
>   — http://linux.die.net/man/1/less